# Django 1.8 : if condition on settings.py using environment variable

Tags: python, django, django-settings, django-1.8

I had an **if** condition on my django 1.7 app to alternate between production and development databases, like so:

```
if os.getenv('SETTINGS_MODE') == 'dev':
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            ...
            }
        }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            ...
        }
    }
```

But I upgraded to django 1.8 and now that no longer works, it always runs the **else** condition. I still have the 'SETTINGS_MODE' variable and it's still set to 'dev'. If I run the django shell with `python manage.py shell`, the the condition evaluates to **True** there:

```
In [1]: import os

In [2]: os.getenv('SETTINGS_MODE') == 'dev'
Out[2]: True
```

And if I change the **if** condition to  `if True:` it works, so I don't know what is wrong, as they should be the same.

How can I do that on django 1.8?

Comment: How are you running your development server? With `./manage.py runserver`? Anyway, try doing `print(os.environ)` and see what environment variables are there.

Comment: Where does SETTINGS_DEV come from anyway? i don;t recall seeing something like that in 1.7? Anyway, you can put print statements in the settings file. Just try print os.getenv('SETTINGS_MODE') == 'dev'   or even print os.getenv('SETTINGS_MODE')  to see what it says

Comment: @rodrigo yes, that's how I was doing it. It just started working again, no idea why, I didn't change anything...

Comment: @e4c5 it's an environment variable from the system, nothing django specific. I use it on my settings.py file so I don't need 2 separate settings.py files or need to change it when I ship it to production. I have this variable set to dev on my development computer and prod on my server, so it automatically switches the settings that I want when I deploy.

Comment: Oh right, silly me not to have thought of that. BTW, a more common approach is to have three separate settings files. one called settings_dev,py settings.py and something like settings_common.py where settings_dev is used exclusively by manage.py and settings.py exclusively by gunicorn or uswgi or whatever. Not saying your strategy is bad - it's pretty good. Just pointing an alternative